# How to change the class assigned in app delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am Using a REFrostedViewController for showing a slide-in menu.And it's working fine in the application .I got a situation where i have to modify the UITableview data-source;like have to  change value in the NSARRAY displaying in table and i am doing it fine .but the problem is that the REFrostedViewController instance created in the appdelegate and at that the instance of DEMOMenuViewController gets also created in the appdelgate will be used throughout the application life cycle until the user the quits the application .

```
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchViewController alloc] init]autorelease]]autorelease];
DEMOMenuViewController *menuController = [[[DEMOMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];

// Create frosted view controller

REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController = [[[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:menuController]autorelease];
```

My issue is that i want the change the DEMOMenuViewController so that i can use the modified/chnaged instance in the REFrostedViewController. If i restart the application i got new values inthe application as i want as new instance gets created upon relaunching the app.

**EDIt**

***Stituation***:application launch and it have three menu item **search**,**login**,**aboutus** when user logged in i need to change the menu to new item say 12 new item.for this i changed the datasoure using a condition **USERIN** that is working fine as i got new array.but the DEMOMenuViewController never gets called again. as instance is created in appdelegate.

What i want to have a new DEMOMenuViewController instance for REFrostedViewController when i got log in the application.

I WAnt to achieve something like below:

```
_menuViewController=[[DEMOMenuViewController alloc]init];

REFrostedViewController *view=[AppDelegateInstance frostedViewController1];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[AppDelegateInstance navigationController];
view=[[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:_menuViewController];
[AppDelegateInstance frostedViewController1]=view;
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear; please improve it.

Comment: see the edit ,i tried to explain more ,if still not clear lemme know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying the rootviewcontroller

```
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchViewController alloc] init]autorelease]]autorelease];
                DEMOMenuViewController *menuController = [[[DEMOMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];

                // Create frosted view controller
                //
                REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController1 = [[[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:menuController]autorelease];

                frostedViewController1.direction = REFrostedViewControllerDirectionLeft;
                frostedViewController1.liveBlurBackgroundStyle = REFrostedViewControllerLiveBackgroundStyleLight;
                frostedViewController1.liveBlur = YES;
                frostedViewController1.delegate = self;

                [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                                  duration:0.5
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                                animations:^{ [[AppDelegateInstance window] setRootViewController:frostedViewController1]; }
                                completion:nil];
```